# How to pass reference of interface inside onClickListener

Tags: java, android

My activity implements ann interface, and onClick method, I want to pass instance of the interface to the constructor of the class "logivVerifyerImpl"
but I cant because "this" keyword will then reference to onclickListener and not to the interface ILoginView.

please let me know how to pass a reference of an interface inside onclickListener??

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ILoginView{
....
....
....

mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username = mEditTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password = mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();
            new LogicVerifyerImpl(this).verify(username, password);//how to pass instance of the interface to the constructor
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of "this":

```
MainActivity.this
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MainActivity.this
```

instead of

```
this
```

only.